# Error: Invalid params when trying to deploy a contract which calls a library function

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, compilation

ecverify.sol

```
// Written by Alex Beregszaszi (@axic), use it under the terms of the MIT license.

pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

library ECVerify {

    function safer_ecrecover(bytes32 hash, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) internal returns (bool, address) {
        bool ret;
        address addr;

        assembly {
            let size := mload(0x40)
            mstore(size, hash)
            mstore(add(size, 32), v)
            mstore(add(size, 64), r)
            mstore(add(size, 96), s)
            ret := call(3000, 1, 0, size, 128, size, 32)
            addr := mload(size)
        }
        return (ret, addr);
    }

    function ecrecovery(bytes32 hash, bytes sig) returns (bool, address) {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;
        if (sig.length != 65)
          return (false, 0);
        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }
        if (v < 27)
          v += 27;
        if (v != 27 && v != 28)
            return (false, 0);
        return safer_ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
    }

    function ecverify(bytes32 hash, bytes sig, address signer) returns (bool) {
        bool ret;
        address addr;
        (ret, addr) = ecrecovery(hash, sig);
        return ret == true && addr == signer;
    }
}
```

ecverify_test.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "ecverify.sol";

contract ECVerifyTest {
    function test_v0() returns (bool) {
        bytes32 hash = 0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad;
        bytes memory sig = "\xac\xa7\xda\x99\x7a\xd1\x77\xf0\x40\x24\x0c\xdc\xcf\x69\x05\xb7\x1a\xb1\x6b\x74\x43\x43\x88\xc3\xa7\x2f\x34\xfd\x25\xd6\x43\x93\x46\xb2\xba\xc2\x74\xff\x29\xb4\x8b\x3e\xa6\xe2\xd0\x4c\x13\x36\xea\xce\xaf\xda\x3c\x53\xab\x48\x3f\xc3\xff\x12\xfa\xc3\xeb\xf2\x00";
        address addr = 0x000e5cb767cce09a7f3ca594df118aa519be5e2b5a;
        return ECVerify.ecverify(hash, sig, addr);
    }

    function test_v1() returns (bool) {
        bytes32 hash = 0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad;
        bytes memory sig = "\xde\xba\xaa\x0c\xdd\xb3\x21\xb2\xdc\xaa\xf8\x46\xd3\x96\x05\xde\x7b\x97\xe7\x7b\xa6\x10\x65\x87\x85\x5b\x91\x06\xcb\x10\x42\x15\x61\xa2\x2d\x94\xfa\x8b\x8a\x68\x7f\xf9\xc9\x11\xc8\x44\xd1\xc0\x16\xd1\xa6\x85\xa9\x16\x68\x58\xf9\xc7\xc1\xbc\x85\x12\x8a\xca\x01";
        address addr = 0x008743523d96a1b2cbe0c6909653a56da18ed484af;
        return ECVerify.ecverify(hash, sig, addr);
    }
}
```

*Note: I'm using `0x008743523d96a1b2cbe0c6909653a56da18ed484af` instead of `0x8743523d96a1b2cbe0c6909653a56da18ed484af` is to avoid the `Warning: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum. If this is not used as an address, please prepend \'00\'.` warning.*

Contract gets compiled successfully.

Transaction options to deploy an instance of `ECVerifyTest` contract:

```
{ from: '0x109a31067644516b04549bddcb473e51fd0cf835',
  data: '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__libraries/ecverify.sol:ECVerify_______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__libraries/ecverify.sol:ECVerify_______946339cdde3294899489948994919390926084909101919080838382156101e5575b8051825260208311156101e557601f1990920191602091820191016101c5565b505050905090810190601f1680156102115780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b5094505050505060206040518083038186803b151561022c57fe5b60325a03f4151561023957fe5b5050604051519450505b50505090565b604080516020810190915260008152905600a165627a7a723058209520a77cb9b8da131594775f11e32a1d24901fafac465dd4fb07bbd9d38eabad0029',
  gas: '0x989680' }
```

Getting an error `[Error: Invalid params]` which is **completely useless**.

Same `gas` and `from` address works fine with other contracts.